# Is there a simple way to ignore index error in c++?

Tags: c++

```
int Square::countmines(){
    int numofmines = 0;
    for (int valuey = y_ - 1; valuey < valuey + 2; valuey ++){
        for (int valuex = x_ -1; valuex < valuex + 2; valuex ++){
            if(lauta_-> at(valuex).at(valuey).returnmine() == true){
            numofmines ++;
            }
        }
```

Im trying to code a minesweeper game in c++  for a school project. Square is an object that has an x and y coordinate, and a boolean value if there is a mine. Count mines calculates how many mines are near the square by going through every square around it and adding +1 to the numofmines value if there is a mine.

The problem is that when counting the nearby mines of a square of a square that is on the edge of the board, the program throws an index error. In python I could just fix it like this:

```
try:
         <MY CODE>
     except IndexError:
         pass
```

Is there a similar way to do it in c++ ?

Comment: You don’t ignore errors. You fix them. Don’t go out of bounds. Just add checks.

Comment: so then detect the edge conditions and adjust as needed.

Comment: If there was, it would be called Javascript...

Comment: Such special cases have to be handled explicitly by the code.

Comment: or add extra cells around the minefield and iterate inside that border. So instead of loop from from 0 to 9 for 10 cells, have 14 cells and loop from 2 to 11

Comment: @pm100 I don't think that's a good option because then they need special code to ensure those dummy cells have valid values, get reset as required, etc. Which is a waste of time when they're ultimately pointless.

Comment: If you don't want to check boundary conditions, then change your board so that there is a buffer around your board, so you don't access memory that is out of bounds.  You'll have to adjust your indices by 1 since you can't declare array bounds starting at -1.

Comment: @underscore_d they are set as empty. trivially easy to do. This is a common technique

Comment: @pm100 Right, it's not as bad as I made out. The 'border' solution can indeed be implemented simply in cases like this and be used to avoid checks and branching. I've even used it in the past! But that was on a Z80, where every cycle mattered; I think on modern hardware, I'd probably want to specifically code for the edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that when counting the nearby mines of a square of a square that is on the edge of the board, the program throws an index error.

Yes, it's telling you not to do that. You don't ignore the error, you fix the code to stop doing that.

You need to make the program detect the [edge case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_case) and handle it differently. That's what programming is about, not just doing the same thing for all cases and ignoring the bugs.

**Edit:**

> Is there a similar way to do it in c++ ?

You need to read about `try` and `catch` in C++.

Comment: I edited my guestion, I think i wasnt specific enough

Comment: I hope you're not trying to learn C++ just from stackoverflow questions. Any C++ book or course should cover how to handle exceptions.

Comment: Amen to that. However, IMO using exceptions is absolutely not a proper way to do this. Your program will be wading through exception handling machinery multiple times for every turn simply because you couldn't be bothered to write code with a decent level of hygiene by using one of the other, suggested solutions. Exceptions are for exceptional circumstances, not saving typing in mundane ones.

Comment: Totally agreed, which is why I decided not to show the code to handle the exceptions. That and the fact that needing to be shown that at all is quite lazy, it's easy to find the answer on the web.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the error by using `[valuex]` instead of `at(values)` etc. That will land you squarely in undefined-behavior-land. Don't do that. There are two straightforward approaches to this problem: add guard squares, or check the boundaries before indexing into the array.

For guard squares, instead of whatever size your array is, increase each dimension by two. When you access the "real" squares, add 1 to each index value. When you're counting, just access the squares in the same way you're doing it now. By putting a border of guard squares around the minefield, you make it possible to use index values that are 1-off from the boundaries of the minefield without going outside the underlying array.

To check the boundaries, just don't use the -1 or +2 indexes when you're on the edge of the minefield.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a lack of abstraction.

If you had a class for the playing field which has a nice accessor function for whether a field is a mine, then you can modify just that accessor to return false for out-of-bounds instead of an error.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate your limits ahead of time and use them, instead of including the calculation in the for loops. You'll also fix your other errors (valuey < valuey+2 is always true until you overflow your integer).

```
int Square::countmines(){
    int numofmines = 0;
    auto lowerx = std::max(x_ - 1, 0);
    auto upperx = std::min(x_ + 1, (int)lauta_->size());
    for (int valuex = lowerx; valuex < upperx; valuex ++){
        auto lowery = std::max(y_ - 1, 0);
        auto uppery = std::min(y_ + 1, (int)lauta_->at(valuex).size());
        for (int valuey = lowery; valuey < uppery; valuey ++){
            if(lauta_-> at(valuex).at(valuey).returnmine() == true){
                numofmines ++;
            }
        }
    }
    return numofmines;
}
```

If you have the width and height stored as values in your class, you can place those size() calls and the cast to int with those valiables instead